# Docker stack container interaction

Tags: docker, sockets, containers

Ok. I have a trouble with understanding of how containers interact with each other in swarm overlay network.
For example I have stack **mystack**.
In that **mystack** I have 2 containers: *mycontainer0* and *mycontainer1*.
After '''docker stack deploy''' the docker give containers another names: *mystack_mycontainer0.1* and *mystack_mycontainer1.1*.
Now I want to make some interaction between containers. For example I want to ping from first container second one. I can do it from shell '''ping *mystack_mycontainer1*'''.
And that works! Good.
Now I want to send from my c++ application UDP packet from first container to another. I want to use unix socket.
But stop... I should use the IP address of destination container in form *192.168.0.23*. But I don't know it, because everything I know is its semantic name *mystack_mycontainer1*.
Whell...how should I tackle this task?

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you are not asking how to get the IP address from the DN. Other than that you may want to use the service name instead, which is resolvable, and has a predictability in name. But note, unless there is at least one healthy container under the service, service will not be resolved either.

Comment: I was not sure that socket can or can't resolve host name by itself. So the best thing that I can do is to manually resolve hostname using getaddrinfo(). Right?